# How can I create a Alexa skill that reminds you whenever an event occurs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create an Alexa skill that reminds you whenever an event happens, in this case whenever a Tweet from a profile comes out which is about every 5-10 minutes. How can I do this? I looked at setting a recurring alarm, but it seems to be for more for a regular period of time.

EDIT: My skill currently loads up and I have an api to load the information I need. I have the api listed on my dependencies. I keep track of previous sessions to keep track of profiles to pull tweets from. Is there a way to make Alexa triggered whenever a Tweet updates? Or have my skill constantly check if there is a new tweet? The skill seems to turn off within a few seconds of no dialog.

Comment: This is quite a complex problem. Try breaking it down into smaller problems and solve each one separately. Then tie the solutions together. Post what you have actually done so far, not just what you looked at. As you encounter smaller problems, ask questions about them or update this question until you've reached your goal.

Comment: The only thing you can do is using Alexa Proactive Events: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html But you will only have a notification (yellow light on Echo) and the skill won't speak unless you will read notification.